# Quantum master equation in the Batalin-Vilkovisky formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, gauge-theory, quantization, brst

I am reading the Section 15.9 of Weinberg's book "The Quantum Theory of Fields, vol. 2". Under a shift $\delta\Psi[\chi]$ in $\Psi[\chi]$, we have

$$
    \begin{split}
     \delta Z&=i\int[d\chi]\,\exp\big(iI_{\Psi}[\chi]\big)
      \left(\frac{\delta_RS[\chi,\chi^{\ddagger}]}{\delta\chi_n^{\ddagger}}
      \right)_{\chi^{\ddagger}=\delta\Psi/\delta\chi}\left(
      \frac{\delta(\delta\Psi[\chi])}{\delta\chi^n}\right) \\
     &=i\int[d\chi]\,\exp\big(iI_{\Psi}[\chi]\big)\left\{\frac{\delta_L}
      {\delta\chi^n}\left(\frac{\delta_RS}{\delta\chi_n^{\ddagger}}
      \delta\Psi\right)-\frac{\delta_R}{\delta\chi_n^{\ddagger}}
      \frac{\delta_LS}{\delta\chi^n}\delta\Psi\right\}_{\chi^{\ddagger}
      =\delta\Psi/\delta\chi} \\
     &=\int[d\chi]\,\exp\big(iI_{\Psi}[\chi]\big)\left\{
      \frac{\delta_RS[\chi,\chi^{\ddagger}]}{\delta\chi_n^{\ddagger}}
      \frac{\delta_LI_{\Psi}[\chi]}{\delta\chi^n}-i\Delta 
      S[\chi,\chi^{\ddagger}]\right\}_{\chi^{\ddagger}=\delta\Psi/
      \delta\chi}\delta\Psi[\chi]  
    \end{split} 
$$

The last line is exactly the same to Eq. (15.9.33). Referring to the definition of antibracket

$$
  (F,G)=\frac{\delta_RF}{\delta\chi^n}\frac{\delta_LG}{\delta\chi_n^{\ddagger}}-
  \frac{\delta_RF}{\delta\chi_n^{\ddagger}}\frac{\delta_LG}{\delta\chi^n}
$$

we can see that the quantum master equation reads

$$
 -(S,S)-2i\Delta S=0 
$$

which has an extra minus sign. I are not sure whether this is a typo or not.
Could someone help me to check this derivation?

Besides, I am also confused by $\delta_L$ and $\delta_R$. Any clarifications 
will be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @soliton: Eq. (15.9.35) in Weinberg's book reads $(S,S)-2i\Delta S=0$, which is the conventional form, and _without_ an extra minus. Is the extra minus something you derive?

Comment: @Qmechanic: Yes. If Eq. (15.9.33) holds, it will have an extra minus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I) Let us first clarify the left and right derivatives. Left derivatives is explained between eq. (15.8.9) and (15.8.10) in Ref. 1. A *left* derivative means a derivative that acts *from* the left. E.g. if $F= \chi G$, where $G$ does not depend on $\chi$, then  $\frac{\delta_LF}{\delta\chi}=G$. Similarly, a *right* derivative acts *from* the right. E.g. if $F= G\chi$, then $\frac{\delta_RF}{\delta\chi}=G$. One may then work out that left and right derivatives are equal up to a sign factor:

$$\tag{A} \frac{\delta_LF}{\delta\chi}~=~(-1)^{(|F|+1)|\chi|}\frac{\delta_RF}{\delta\chi}.$$

Here $|F|$ denotes the Grassmann parity of $F$. Note in particular that the left and right derivative of the gauge fermion $\Psi[\chi]$ are the same:

$$\tag{B} \frac{\delta_L\Psi}{\delta\chi}~=~\frac{\delta_R\Psi}{\delta\chi}, \qquad |\Psi|~=~1.
$$

II) Now let us consider the [Batalin-Vilkovisky formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism). We start with the full quantum master action $S[\chi,\chi^{\ddagger}]$, which depends on fields $\chi^n$ and antifields $\chi^{\ddagger}_n$.

The odd Laplacian is originally defined in eq. (16b) of Ref. 2 as

$$\tag{16b} \Delta_{BV}~:=~ \frac{\delta_R}{\delta\chi^n}\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\chi^{\ddagger}_n}. $$

Ref. 1 defines (wrongly) the odd Laplacian as

$$\tag{15.9.34} \Delta_{SW}~:=~ \frac{\delta_R}{\delta\chi^{\ddagger}_n}\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\chi^n}. $$

One may show that the two definitions (16b) and (15.9.34) are related as

$$\tag{C} \Delta_{BV}F~=~(-1)^{|F|+1}\Delta_{SW}F. $$

In particular the two definitions (16b) and (15.9.34) differ by a sign

$$\tag{D} \Delta_{BV} S~=~-\Delta_{SW} S, \qquad |S|~=~0, $$

when applied to the action $S$, which is Grassmann-even $|S|=0$.

III) The Quantum Master Equation (QME) reads in Ref. 2

$$\tag{16a} \frac{1}{2}(S,S)~=~i\hbar\Delta_{BV} S,$$

while the QME in Ref. 1 reads

$$\tag{15.9.35} \frac{1}{2}(S,S)~=~i\hbar\Delta_{SW} S.$$

So OP is right. Eqs. (15.9.34) and (15.9.35) are mutually inconsistent. There is a wrong sign in Ref. 1 in either eq. (15.9.34) or eq. (15.9.35).

References:

1. S. Weinberg, *The Quantum Theory of Fields, Vol. 2,* 1996.
2. I.A. Batalin and G.A. Vilkovisky, *Gauge Algebra and Quantization,* Phys. Lett. B 102 (1981) 27–31.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is very helpful. I also read the Ref. 2, but I misunderstood that the $\delta_L$ in Ref. 1 is the same to the $\delta_R$ in Ref. 2.

Comment: I have another question. Why do we define $\delta_L$ as a action from the left? This is opposite to the definition of this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_and_right_derivative) where $f \stackrel{\leftarrow }{\partial }_x g = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot g$.

Comment: As always different authors have different conventions. There exist different conventions for left and right derivatives. Similarly, there exist different conventions for left and right [group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action), and so forth. The Wikipedia page that you mention is not trustworthy in its current state. I might improve it at some point in the future.